# How do I parse an api when some usernames have weird symbols?

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I am currently trying to get data from the Tracker Network Apex Legends API. However, I have run into a problem. I can get certain user's info back, but if a user has a space in their name or just an underscore or something like that. Then I will get an error that will say this.[image]
Here is my current code:

```
        struct Store: Codable {
            let data: DataClass

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case data = "data"
            }
        }

        struct DataClass: Codable {
            let id: String
            let type: String
            let children: [Child]
            let metadata: DataMetadata
            let stats: [Stat]

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case id = "id"
                case type = "type"
                case children = "children"
                case metadata = "metadata"
                case stats = "stats"
            }
        }

        struct Child: Codable {
            let id: String
            let type: String
            let metadata: ChildMetadata
            let stats: [Stat]

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case id = "id"
                case type = "type"
                case metadata = "metadata"
                case stats = "stats"
            }
        }

        struct ChildMetadata: Codable {
            let legendName: String
            let icon: String
            let bgimage: String

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case legendName = "legend_name"
                case icon = "icon"
                case bgimage = "bgimage"
            }
        }

        struct Stat: Codable {
            let metadata: StatMetadata
            let value: Int
            let percentile: Double?
            let rank: Int?
            let displayValue: String
            let displayRank: String

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case metadata = "metadata"
                case value = "value"
                case percentile = "percentile"
                case rank = "rank"
                case displayValue = "displayValue"
                case displayRank = "displayRank"
            }
        }

        struct StatMetadata: Codable {
            let key: String
            let name: String
            let categoryKey: StatsCategoryOrder
            let categoryName: CategoryName
            let isReversed: Bool

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case key = "key"
                case name = "name"
                case categoryKey = "categoryKey"
                case categoryName = "categoryName"
                case isReversed = "isReversed"
            }
        }

        enum StatsCategoryOrder: String, Codable {
            case combat = "combat"
            case game = "game"
            case weapons = "weapons"
        }

        enum CategoryName: String, Codable {
            case combat = "Combat"
            case game = "Game"
            case weapons = "Weapons"
        }

        struct DataMetadata: Codable {
            let statsCategoryOrder: [StatsCategoryOrder]
            let platformID: Int
            let platformUserHandle: String
            let accountID: String
            let cacheExpireDate: String
            let level: Int

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case statsCategoryOrder = "statsCategoryOrder"
                case platformID = "platformId"
                case platformUserHandle = "platformUserHandle"
                case accountID = "accountId"
                case cacheExpireDate = "cacheExpireDate"
                case level = "level"
            }
        }
```

My code for getting the Json data:

```
    let uRl = URL(string: "https://public-api.tracker.gg/apex/v1/standard/profile/5/TwitchTV_Madzzy")
    if let unwrappedURL = uRl {
        var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
        request.addValue("3418ac17-824a-414c-a36c-3c7f0da6f856", forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key")
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // you should put in error handling code, too
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Store.self, from: data) as Store

               //print(json.data)



                //account level
                print("Level: \(json.data.metadata.level)")
                print("Character: \(json.data.children.map{$0.metadata.legendName})")

                let title1 = json.data.children[0].stats[0].metadata.name
                print("\(title1): \(json.data.children.map{$0.stats[0].value})")

                let title2 = json.data.children[0].stats[0].metadata.name
                print("\(title2): \(json.data.children[0].stats[1].value)")

                let title3 = json.data.children[0].stats[2].metadata.name
                print("\(title3): \(json.data.children[0].stats[2].value)")

               print(json.data.children.map{$0.metadata.icon})
               print(json.data.children.map{$0.stats[0].metadata.name})
               print(json.data.children.map{$0.stats.map{$0.metadata.name}})

                print(json.data.children[0].stats[1].metadata.name)



            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

And then here is the new code that I am attempting to use in order to handle usernames with spaces or odd characters. I don't know if this last one is correct. If it is, I am not sure how to get the json from it. For some reason I am only able to get the httpResponse.

```
    let headers = [
    "TRN-Api-Key": "3418ac17-824a-414c-a36c-3c7f0da6f856",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "3c891d92-427e-49a1-9887-c64ff620846a"]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://public-api.tracker.gg/apex/v1/standard/profile/5/TwitchTV_Madzzy")! as URL,
                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse!)
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

Yes, I am using PostMan for this section of code, but I would really like to know how I can handle weird usernames without using the "Postman-Token" and still get the json form the api.

Comment: In do-try-catch block if some error occurs, just print `error` and **not** its `localizedDescription`. It tells what is the exact problem: `print(error)`

Comment: @RobertDresler I got this "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "stats", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "value", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <3.31> does not fit in Int.", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: The error is crystal clear: The value of the coding path `data/stats[2]/value` is a Double. Declare `value` as Double.

Comment: @vadian okay, so this is weird. So when I use the above username with the value needs to be a Double but if I were to type in another username I get this. (I assume it needs to be int again) "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"data\", intValue: nil) (\"data\").", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: This error says that there is no key `data` on the top level of the JSON. An `Int` can be decoded as `Double` but not vice versa.

Comment: @vadian okay that last error was my bad, the user had a different platform and I didn't change it. Everything seems fine now after changing the value to Double

Comment: @vadian Upon reading some stuff. I think this was the issue, so please correct me if I am wrong. The Value was so large that it was exceeding the boundaries of Int, so a Double was required instead?

Comment: No, according to the first error the value contains fractional digits and a decimal separator.

Comment: @vadian Now I see it, alright thank you very much for your time. Cannot believe it was so simple.